# About random variable in Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I have a simple question.

If $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are two random variable on $(\Omega, P)$, they will be two functions, $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$, from $\Omega$ to R.

In case, $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ are identically distribution, then $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are equal or not. I proved they must be equal, but I am not sure.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean the functions are from $\Omega$ to $P$, or $\Omega$ to $R$, or $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

No they need not be equal as random variables in general. Consider a *fair* coin. Suppose you denote heads by 1 and tails by -1, while your friend denotes heads by -1 and tails by 1. Your random variable $X_1=-X_2$ (your friend's random variable). Thus $X_1\neq X_2$, but both of them have the same distribution.
\begin{align*}P(X_1=1)&=P(X_2=1)=\frac{1}{2}\\
P(X_1=-1)&=P(X_2=-1)=\frac{1}{2}\end{align*}